# NetApp - Copy volume data to LUN on same filer

Tags: copy, netapp, lun, disk-volume

I'm trying to copy a volume `/vol/Archive_chi` to a LUN (LUN volume = `/vol/ArchiveLUN_chi` ; LUN = `ArchiveLUN` ; LUN PATH = `/vol/ArchiveLUN_chi/ArchiveLUN`).

I tried `ndmpcopy /vol/Archive_chi /vol/ArchiveLUN_chi` and `ndmpcopy /vol/Archive_chi /vol/ArchiveLUN_chi/ArchiveLUN` without any success.

I found snap-mirror/-vault to be to impractical in our current environment/setup.

I am now trying to use `vol copy start /vol/Archive_chi /vol/ArchiveLUN_chi` or more directly `vol copy start /vol/Archive_chi /vol/ArchiveLUN_chi/ArchiveLUN` but those are erroring out with `Volume doesn't exist: /vol/ArchiveLUN_chi` and `Volume doesn't exist: /vol/ArchiveLUN_chi/ArchiveLUN` respectively.

I was able to get `vol copy` to work only after simply using the volume name `vol copy start Archive_chi ArchiveLUN_chi` (volume to volume), but `vol copy start Archive_chi ArchiveLUN` or `vol copy start Archive_chi ArchiveLUN_chi/ArchiveLUN` (volume to LUN) I get `Volume doesn't exist:" error`.

I've seen a variety of formats used online and in the KB. How can I copy a volume to a LUN? Maybe that's only available when using the `-s` or `-S` snapshot flags? Which formatting should I use? I'm on 7-mode.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A LUN is something you present to a server that allows it to do scsi reads and scsi writes. It will, of course, install its own filesystem on this scsi disk, but that's not something Netapp can see. All it sees are the contents of each scsi block that's been modified.

What are you really trying to do? Do you have data in a volume that you want to put into a LUN? The way to do that would be to present that volume to the server with access to the LUN and copy it using the server's OS.

Comment: Yep, I see, very unfortunate. I guess I'll have to take the old fashioned `robocopy` approach :'( Thanks.